# Instead of using Laravel local user data, how to login to Laravel using Prestashop customers data

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, prestashop-1.6

i want to ask a question regarding the login to Laravel using Prestashop customers data.

Recently, I'm doing a new project whereby in Laravel user login, I want to use Prestashop users (customers) data. That is we will not using Laravel own local user data, but we will use prestashop customers data.

How do I integrate Laravel with Prestashop in user login? Create custome authentication?

And how do I modified the AuthenticateUser in Laravel? I have been searching online in this matter, but I can't find any related.

Answer (score 2):

You may find some libraries that may or may not facilitate this, however, when I needed a similar feature, I simply developed it myself. In brief:

1) In Laravel create a service to authenticate the user through the PrestaShop API.
2) Depending on the response from PrestaShop, you can create a USER in Laravel and instead of a password, save an access token. Same as you would do with say FB login but obviously cannot use Socialite direct - albeit you can extend it or copy its code.
3) You can if wish copy the PrestaShop credentials and allow the user to login directly through Laravel in the future.

There are other methods you can use instead of my suggestion, such as continuously update the Laravel's users' tables from PrestaShop but this is not very consistent and secure.

Comment: Hi @Keith, thanks for the suggestion. I think no. 1 method is acceptable. Do you have any similar coding for reference?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the code is it belongs to my client but this is fairly easy to implement. Just check the PrestaShop docs to see which API routes you need to use and what they return. Then use that return data to create a Laravel User model.

Comment: You mean I had to grab the Prestashop customers data and stored them in my laravel local user database based on what you mention?

Comment: Yes. The visitor will come to your Laravel app and there'll be a link to login as an existing customer. That link will go to a controller (and probably an App service), queries PrestaShop customers thorugh the API, if a customer with the same email and password exists then your service will create a Laravel User and a secure token for consequent logins so that you only need to do this once per customer.

Comment: I appreciated your replied & explanation, can you roughly show the coding and the flow. Can I chat further with you in the email? Another is if the customer change their password in Prestashop, will the laravel queries prestashop customers again for checking?

Comment: Contact me at keith-mifsud.me. Happy to help. > mifsud.k@gmail.com

Comment: Much appreciate

Comment: Hi Keith, I had send the email to you

Comment: Hello but do you know the hash algorithm used by presta shop?

Comment: You should not need the hash algo. Hashes are a one-time thing and they cannot be "un"hashed. Don't confuse hashing with encryption :)

Comment: @camillo777 you get your user to enter their Prestashop password on your app and then send it to Presta (not hashed--of course) through the API for verification. Presta will return 200 or 401 code or similar status.

Comment: So you are sending the password not hashed to PrestaShop API? Do you have any more information or document on PrestaShop API, I cannot find any docs apart from the endpoints. I would like to make a mobile app that use the PrestaShop product API with login and search. Do you know if it is possible? Thank you

Comment: This might be useful: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/webservice/#about-crud-rest